# MongoDB Remove WiredTiger files

Tags: mongodb

I'm running ***3.2 mongodb*** version.
I was removing all my data of my collections to start from new fresh data and reduce the disk space. But I was found in **/var/lib/mongodb/** directrory there is large WiredTiger files over 30GB.
After searching i used `db.repairDatabase()` command but I got only more 6GB in space.

Can I just remove the ***.wt** files ?

Is this can affect damages on my database ?

Removing collections and create them again can reduce the space?

Best regards